# Stop syncing Safari History through iCloud between 1 or more computers or iOS devices

Tags: icloud, safari

If I uncheck the Safari option under iCloud settings either on a Mac or an iOS device will the links stop syncing between devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Links, browsing history, open tabs. Everything should stop syncing on the device you uncheck Safari on.